# Where did St. Catherine of Siena say: “Preach the Truth as if you had a million voices. It is silence that kills the world.”?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, saint, catherine-of-siena

Where did St. Catherine of Siena say: “Preach the Truth as if you had a million voices. It is silence that kills the world.”?

<sup>quoted in [this article](https://www.lifesitenews.com/opinion/the-heart-of-the-catholic-churchs-current-crisis-is-the-abandonment-of-law-and-doctrine/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from [Lettera 16, "A uno grande prelato"](http://www.clerus.org/bibliaclerusonline/it/eki.htm#q) ("to a great prelate"):

> Oimé, non più tacere! Gridate con centomiglia di lingue. Veggo che, per lo tacere, el mondo è guasto, la Sposa di Cristo è impalidita
>
> <sup>O alas, be silent no more! Shout with a hundred thousand tongues. I see that, through silence, the world is broken, the Bride of Christ is impaled</sup>